# How do I override or alter the inheritance of the child elements when my datacontext is set on the parent element?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, data-binding

**Disclaimer** I feel like this is a fairly simple question, so i must reiterate that I did look for an answer and couldn't find anything!

Not sure if I am asking the question correctly, but I will tell you this. I am working on becoming more familiar with MVVM, so I am messing around with a ridiculously simple project of two stackpanels, ten textboxes, and some simple binding. Everything works now, since I have two panels, which separates my boxes and lets me set two datacontext.

My question is this:

a) is it possible to set the datacontext on a parent element (Stackpanel) and have half of my child elements (textboxes) use that context via inheritance and then give the other half of the elements A DIFFERENT data context?

and

b) if this is possible, how??

Thanks people-smarter-than-I

Here is the code that is trying so hard, but not really doing anything I want it to be doing:

XAML

```
   <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,8,0,75" Width="224" DataContext="{Binding Path=Customer}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"  Height="28" Name="label1"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MiddleName}"  Height="28" Name="l2"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=LastName}"  Height="28" Name="l3"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CompanyName}"  Height="28" Name="l4"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=EmailAddress}"  Height="28" Name="l5"/>

        <!--I want the next five TextBox elements to bind to a different datacontext-->

        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"  Height="28" Name="label11"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MiddleName}"  Height="28" Name="l21"/>
        <TextBox   Text="{Binding Path=LastName}"  Height="28" Name="l1lgh3"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CompanyName}"  Height="28" Name="l1hj4"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=EmailAddress}" Height="28"/>
   </StackPanel>
   </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind C#

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

View Model

```
   public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        PopulateCustomerInfo();
    }

    private Customer customer;
    public Customer Customer
    {
        get { return customer; }
        set
        {
            customer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Customer");
        }
    }

    private Customer customer2;
    public Customer Customer2
    {
        get { return customer2; }
        set
        {
            customer2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Customer");
        }
    }


    private void PopulateCustomerInfo()
    {
        AdventureWorksLTE ctx = new AdventureWorksLTE();
        this.Customer = (from c in ctx.Customers
                   select c).FirstOrDefault();
        this.Customer2 = (from c in ctx.Customers
                          orderby c.FirstName descending
                          select c).FirstOrDefault();

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handle = PropertyChanged;
        if (handle != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handle(this, e);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do various things like changing the `DataContext` locally on all those lower `TextBoxes`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" DataContext="..."/>
```

The question really is though: What do you want to achieve? Does it make sense to even set the DataContext on the StackPanel?

Maybe you should not and use a longer path instead:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Customer.FirstName}"  Height="28" Name="label1"/>
```

It all depends on what properties are going to be used in the child controls, if most or all of them are in `Customer`, sure, set it to keep the bindings short. If you need the main view model in some places you can use [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource.aspx) to get to a control with the right data context and change the path accordingly. (`DataContext.*`, data context appears in the path as a different source is specified)

Comment: ` <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Customer2.FirstName}" Height="28" Name="label11"/>  <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MiddleName}" DataContext="{Binding Path=Customer2}" Height="28" Name="l21"/>`

Comment: I tried both methods and it does not seem to be working.  Is there something else that I need to set to allow this to happen?  As far as your question goes, I just want to know if it is possible and how to do it. I am not thinking of any practical use for it right now, just doing some learning exercises.

Comment: @davidisawesome: In the first method the `DataContext `of the lower `TextBoxes` is still the `Customer` so all bindings with just a path are relative to that, if you have a `DataContext` bound to `Customer2` the binding will look for `Customer2` in the `Customer`, you need something like `{Binding DataContext.Customer2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}` which goes up to where the DataContext is still the whole VM.

Comment: @davidisawesome: For the second method as noted the `DataContext` must not be set on the `StackPanel`, so all bindings in the `TextBoxes` start with the full VM and the path is absolute.

Answer (score 1):

most simple way is to have two StackPanels within the first one, grouping 5 by 5 your textboxes, first one having customer as datacontext, second one having customer2.

The stackPanel and (5 textboxes) content could even be defined as a DataTemplate (having no key or name but rather a DataType = {x:Type local:Customer }  (where local is your clr namespace) ) and you would just use 2 ContentPresenters having content binding to Customer / Customer 2, that would 'automatically' display what you want.